# What do these Spring debug messages mean?

Tags: spring, message, spring-jdbc

I use Spring IoC in my stand-alone Java application. When the application starts it creates a log with start-up info. Some messages I don't understand, please help me to understand them and explain how to fix them if they must be fixed? Also I am curious: Is there any danger for my application stability because of these messages?

Messages that scare me off starts with word "Unable". At the moment the application works quite well.

```
INFO - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@52cc95d: startup date     [Thu Jun 02 16:02:12 MSD 2011]; root of context hierarchy
INFO - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [application-config.xml]
DEBUG - Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
DEBUG - Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
DEBUG - Loaded schema mappings: {http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd}
DEBUG - Loading bean definitions
DEBUG - Loaded 3 bean definitions from location pattern [application-config.xml]
DEBUG - Bean factory for org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@52cc95d: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@33aae94f: defining beans [propertyPlaceholderConfigurer,dbWorker,connectionPool]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer'
DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Finished creating instance of bean 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer'
INFO - Loading properties file from class path resource [config.properties]
DEBUG - Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@49bdc9d8]
DEBUG - Unable to locate ApplicationEventMulticaster with name 'applicationEventMulticaster': using default [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@255d17d7]
INFO - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@33aae94f: defining beans [propertyPlaceholderConfigurer,dbWorker,connectionPool]; root of factory hierarchy
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'propertyPlaceholderConfigurer'
DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'dbWorker'
DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'dbWorker'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'dbWorker' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'connectionPool'
DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'connectionPool'
DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'connectionPool' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG - Finished creating instance of bean 'connectionPool'
DEBUG - Finished creating instance of bean 'dbWorker'
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'connectionPool'
DEBUG - Unable to locate LifecycleProcessor with name 'lifecycleProcessor': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor@4b1c2b67]
DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is just debug level output which you probably don't need. Essentially it's telling you that you haven't defined any particular classes which override its default functionality, so it's going to use the default functionality. There's nothing to worry about here.

Comment: Hi Phill, thank for your reply. Actually I understand it myself (If I managed to write app :-). I need more details. What those unable things actually mean. Unable - is a bad word for app that counts money... I think. But you reply relaxed me a bit...

Comment: @MinimeDJ In that case I suggest you read the Javadocs for MessageSource, ApplicationEventMulticaster and LifecycleProcessor. The whole point of Spring is that you can customise bits of it. All that log output is telling you is that it's using default functionality and not custom functionality.

Comment: @MinimeDJ: debug-level log messages are things you don't need to worry about. set your root logging level to warn, then add lower logging levels for specific packages you want more details about, like your application code.

Answer (score 2):

If you have explicitly defined any of those beans then you might have a problem as Spring would be injecting the wrong type, since it is not finding your custom bean. However, if you have not defined these beans, then these messages are benign. Spring is just letting you know that the default bean is being used - as @Phill has already answered.

Comment: Ok, then I accept Phills answer. Thank you for your feedback!